# Keras+tensorflow batch image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have service which  should make response on classification of 10-20 images per request.

now  I process then one by one:

```
 with model_store.some_graph.as_default():
        with model_store.some_session.as_default():
            for i in images:
                x = image.img_to_array(i)
                x = preprocess_input(x)
                x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
                pred = model_store.top_model.predict(x)[0]
```

It takes 3-4 seconds( On CPU instance ) 
Is it possible  to process them at one call? And if yes can it give any performance boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a batch of images, something of shape `(batch_size, W, H, C)`. In your case collect images to a list and then concatenate into single tensor:

```
def process_img(x):
  x = image.img_to_array(x)
  x = preprocess_input(x)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  return x
imgs = [process_img(i) for i in images]
imgs = np.concatenate(*imgs, axis=0)
preds = model_store.top_model.predict(imgs, batch_size=32)
```

Now the model will predict with batches of 32 images at a time. This might speed things up depending on your hardware. As a result, you will get all the predictions in one go as well.

Comment: had wrap the first argument to concatenate in square brackets for this to work for me